# A straightforward way of how to compile a program using GNUstep makefiles?

Tags: objective-c, makefile, gnustep

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSLog(@"Hello World!");

  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

This is my program. I have run it on my friends iMac, and there are no problems with the 
code. How do I make the makefiles I have been hearing about on GNUstep?

Comment: What do you mean by "makefiles I have been hearing about?" Have you started with the GNUstep developers tools? http://www.gnustep.org/experience/DeveloperTools.html

Comment: Yes, I have installed the latest MSYS, Core, and Devel packages, installed in that order. I have read about "make files that people are able to use to compile their programs in GNUstep. What are those, and how do you create them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [GNUstep Makefile tutorial](http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/)? Also the [GNUstep make documentation](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/make_1.html)? You should find `common.make` in the packages you installed already.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me an example of putting the makefile definition into my code? They are not very clear on the whereabouts of where you put each line in your code. Thanks again!